# Numerical Analysis - Rounding after calculating uncertainty of a function

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

I successfully calculated the uncertainty associated to a group of functions:

- `f(x) +- 0,0104`
- `g(x) +- 0,0155`
- `h(x) +- 0,5445`

The problem is the result of these functions are rounded to the nearest integer number as in: `round(f(35)) = round(17,7549) = 18`. Considering `t(x) = round(h(x))` how can I calculate the uncertainty of `t(x)`?

Comment: Logically thinking, the difference between $f(x)$ and $\text{round}(f(x))$ is $$
\left|f(x) -  \text{round}(f(x))\right| \leq 0.5
$$
so from this you can deduce something ...

Comment: @MattiP. Does that mean if I calculate the uncertainty of `f(x) + 0.5` and `f(x) - 0.5` the resulting uncertainty is the same as `round(f(x))`?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to consider the effect of rounding as a uniform random variable $\delta$ ([Widrow et al.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/492748)). Then you model your uncertainty as a random variable $\epsilon$. The result is that
$$ t(x) \approx h(x) + \delta + \epsilon = h(x) + \nu$$

If you model $\epsilon$ as a uniform random variable too, then the density total noise $\nu$ will be the convolution of the densities of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$, which is a triangular-shaped density (convolution of two rectangles). From there, you can compute the standard deviation and other quantities of interest.